# How to install the grub image on a bios_grub partition and esp at the same time?

Tags: grub2, uefi

I need this to boot from portable GPT hdd on computers of both types(BIOS and EFI).

Comment: And will this scheme work?

Answer (score 0):

Using GRUB for both modes can be problematic, because the `grub.cfg` file may need to be subtly different for the two modes -- or at least, I've seen problem reports from people who try to use the same file in both modes. Thus, I recommend using one boot loader in BIOS mode and another one in EFI mode. It's likely to be easiest to set up GRUB in BIOS mode and another boot loader for EFI mode. See [my Web page on the topic](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) for a rundown of what's available. rEFInd is likely to be the easiest to set up and manage, but ELILO can work well, too, if you're comfortable with a LILO-style configuration file.